# Expression.Error: The column 'Amount' of the table wasn't found

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I know there have been topics on this error, but I've reviewed them and they haven't been helpful.  I am trying to add a custom column with the absolute value of column "Amount".

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2 (causing the error):

[image]

Based on other threads it would seem to be a typo, however, that doesn't seem to be the case here.  Additionally, I have 4 Excel files like this that I'm importing with the same steps - 2 work and 2 don't.

Much obliged for any ideas.

Edit:
Here is the full code from the Advanced Editor

```
let
Source = SharePoint.Files("https://netorgftxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/", [ApiVersion = 15]),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Folder Path], "FName LName")),
#"Filtered Rows5" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each ([Name] <> "2019-07-29T08_13_08+00_00Customer_List.xlsx" and [Name] <> "2019-07-29T08_13_08+00_00Invoice_Listing_TTM.xlsx" and [Name] <> "2019-07-29T08_13_08+00_00Revenue_by_Customer_for_Dashboard.xlsx")),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows5", each Text.Contains([Name], "Company")),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows2",{{"Date modified", type date}}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", let latest = List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Date modified]) in each [Date modified] = latest),
#"Filtered Rows3" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each Text.Contains([Name], "Expense")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows3",{"Content"}),
Content = #"Removed Other Columns"{0}[Content],
#"Imported Excel" = Excel.Workbook(Content),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Imported Excel",{"Data"}),
Data = #"Removed Other Columns1"{0}[Data],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Data,{"Column1"}),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Removed Columns",4),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Custom", each "Company"),
#"Filtered Rows4" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Transaction Type] = "Bill" or [Transaction Type] = "Expense")),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows4",{{"Amount", type number}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Adjusted Expense Amount", each Number.Abs([Amount]))
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

Comment: See if there's any special character in the column. You may apply the "if solution" given in the answer and see if it returns any null then look for the original value in the source column to find a culprit.

Comment: Please post the full code from the Advanced Editor

Comment: Thanks - I pasted the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was with line 8 of the code which was not specific enough. Two types of files were being imported, causing an error.  Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have values in your `Amount` column which will throw an error when you use the `Abs()` function. This could happen when you have text in your column, because the `Abs()` functino expects number type formats.

Either you clean your `Amount` column first (so that you just have number formats) or you add an additional check in your M expression.

This for example:

```
= if Value.Is(Value.FromText([Column1]), type number) 
  then Number.Abs(Number.From([Column1])) 
  else null
```

Comment: Step 1 shows the conversion of any text type to number as he adds Abs() in step 2, though your solution will work on source column if any text needs to converted absolute number.

Comment: Yes and if he has a text type in his column he will get an error after Step 1 is applied.

Answer (score 0):

It should be one of following cases:

1. Typo in Amount column name.
2. (more likely) You refer to wrong step. Table on #"Changed Type1" step doesn't contain Amount column.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the full code above, and I can't seem to find where either case exists.  #2 was my first thought, too.